# Slow download on small file using C# WebClient

Tags: c#, webclient

I am trying to download a series of files using WebClient class, but it is extremely slow to even download a small file. I am new to using HTTP in C#, so I am not sure why this is happening.

The code I have written is:

```
private void GetPhoto()
{
    string url = "http://www.glam-ou-rama.co.uk/users/600/gallery/";
    long fileNumber = 39658719305555612;
    string fileExtension = ".jpg";
    string targetFile = url + fileNumber.ToString() + fileExtension;
    txt_Gross.Text = targetFile;
    if (RemoteFileExists(targetFile))
    {
        //create path 
        txt_Exists.Text = "TRUE";
        string finalPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\saved\\" + fileNumber + fileExtension;
        txt_Exists.Text = finalPath;
        using (System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            client.Proxy = null;
            client.DownloadFile(targetFile, @finalPath);
        }
    }


}
```

And the RemoteFileExists method:

```
private bool RemoteFileExists(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            //Creating the HttpWebRequest
            System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url) as System.Net.HttpWebRequest;
            //Setting the Request method HEAD, you can also use GET too.
            request.Method = "HEAD";
            //Getting the Web Response.
            System.Net.HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as System.Net.HttpWebResponse;
            //Returns TURE if the Status code == 200
            return (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        catch
        {
            //Any exception will returns false.
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How slow is slow? And what does that `RemoteFileExists` do? If it makes a connection, it may slows down the method.

Comment: RemoteFileExists tests the same URI to check the HTTP header for a 200 status. Time taken is about 5-10 seconds for a 30 kb image.

Comment: I will edit the question to include the RemoteFileExists function

Comment: I don't see any buggy snippet which can cause such behavior whats inside the **RemoteFileExists(string targetFile)** hope full you will sending request and checking for error or success.. right?? you can minimize this request but only getting header.. not the full body of the request.

Comment: Why don't you try request.GetResponseStream() to fetch the file?

Comment: @user3175451 You made a request inside `RemoteFileExists` (it actually downloads the file there!). Instead of such checks, use `try/catch` around `client.DownloadFile`.

Comment: @KhanhNguyen it will not download the file .. he clearly stated **request.Method = "HEAD";** it will not download the file.. it will download the header only.

Comment: @user3175451 `RemoteFileExists` takes 5-10 sec as u told.. for local machine or you are accessing file from a machine over the internet.?? we i also have the same way in one of my project and its working perfectly.. no issue at all..

Comment: @DeepakSharma, I am accessing over the internet. My intention, once I speed this up a bit, was to loop over a range of integers on the fileNumber variable, to download a range of files if they exist. That said, however, this simple image should never take 10 seconds to download.

Comment: better approach is minimize the request to remote server by writing your custom web service at file server.. Send the request to take WebService which will respond the **FileNotFoundExceptio -- Custom Exception)** or **File itself if found there**

Comment: but I am still confused why its working smoothly in my project..!! :O

Comment: Side note: server can control speed of download... I can stream 1K down over several minutes if I send couple bytes a second... And you'll have no way to speed it up.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason that i don't know , usually WebClient for download itens are very slow, try to use HttpClient insted. if you want to donwload the file for the user computer your code may be like these:

```
        using System.Net.Http;
        using System.IO;

        string url = "http://www.glam-ou-rama.co.uk/users/600/gallery/";
        long fileNumber = 39658719305555612;
        string fileExtension = ".jpg";
        string targetFile = url + fileNumber.ToString() + fileExtension;

        string targetsite = $@"C:/{fileNumber}{fileExtension}";

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            Stream stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(targetFile);
            FileStream fileStream = File.Create(targetsite);                
            stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
            fileStream.Close();
        }
```